# Force frame-title-format to update?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I wanted to use the title bar to display some useful information for emacs. Currently I use frame-title-format. However, the title bar only updates when emacs "wants" to update it. For example saving file, or reached top or bottom of buffer. Is there a command to update the title bar manually?

The command I used is

```
(setq frame-title-format 
  '("%b  %*  " 
    (:eval (number-to-string (wy-count-word-section))) 
    " / %i" "%n"))
```

where wy-count-word-section is a numeric variable.

Comment: Maybe start by identifying when exactly you'd like to have it updated. This should be related to when you are looking at it. It could be linkable then to something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like modeline, using `force-mode-line-update` will update frame title, too.